# Update actionbar in differenct activities after AsyncTask finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-actionbar

I'm going to develop an application for an online shop. Whenever a user wants to add some item to shopping cart, It must be checked with item availability in shop and then add it to shopping cart.
For this action I developed an AsyncTask like this:

```
class AddItemTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //try to check if item is available to order
        availabilityFlag = isItemAvailable(currentItem);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //what should I do know?
        if (availabilityFlag==true){

           addItemToShoppingCart(currentItem);
           //what should I do now to update Cart Icon?
        }
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

If item is available, the shopping cart icon which is located on ActionBar must be updated. The problem is, this update might happen when we left current activity and moved to another one. I want to know how should I update the actionBar Icon without considering which activity is running?

*Notice:* cart icon is visible in ActionBar of all activities.

Comment: You should create global container for your data from asynctask and in onResume() in activities/fragments update caption of toolbar or actionbar

Comment: Instead of using `Void, Void, Void` you can use `Void, Void, Boolean` and can return the availability in `doInBackground` and in `onPostExecute` you can have the boolean. As Far as the your question is concerned it seems like you need to use some storage either file or db to store your data for offline purposes, and a service which will update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store the items put into the cart in SQLite, and update the icon in your actionbar based on the results after querying the table for cart items.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i would use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/run-background-service/create-service.html#CreateClass) for calls(e.g. `isItemAvailable`) towards the remote server. After a result has been proceed in the service a [broadcast](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) can be sent to notify the other components of the app. By this way, you get lots of flexibilty. Your background datas can be stored in static class if they are only valid for your current app session, but if you need persistent storage [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference) or SQLite is your way.

For updating your activties with valid datas, it should be done in the `onResume`.
 In this method you should:
 1. call your service->get the broadcast-> update the activty or
 2. read background datas from one of above -> update activity.